# Count of three type of nodes in Binary Search Tree (Recursively)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function that will count the three type of nodes in a Binary Search Tree in Python. It would count and return the total number of nodes with 0 children, 1 child, and 2 children. I have noticed that a recursively method would be best for this rather than iterative way.

```
def node_counts(self):
    """
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    Returns the number of the three types of nodes in a BST.
    Use: zero, one, two = bst.node_counts()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Postconditions:
      returns
      zero - number of nodes with zero children (int)
      one - number of nodes with one child (int)
      two - number of nodes with two children (int)
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    """
    zero, one, two = self._node_counts_aux(self._root)
    return zero, one, two

def _node_counts_aux(self, node):
    zero, one, two = 0, 0, 0
    if node is not None:
        if not node._right and not node._left:
            zero = 1 # I understand that the problem is here.
        if node._left and node._right:
            two = 1 + self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[2] + self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[2]
        if node._left or node._right:
            one = 1 + self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[1] + self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[1]
    return zero, one, two

"""
I am testing with this Tree:
        36
       /  \
      /    \
     6      50
    / \     / \
   4   17  49  84
       /   /   / \
      12  42  65 85

The output with this code comes to: (0, 6, 4).

"""
```

The one column is wrong in a sense but in a sense also right. That's not my concern. 
My concern is zero not being counted.
zero is being set as 0 so how can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry the function is called _node_counts_aux. Its just a helper function that does the recursion to the main function.

Comment: Are you using a class of any sort?

Comment: The class is a custom binary search tree ADT. It has the attribute root. It uses another short binary search tree node class which has 3 attributes value, left, and right. Where left and right are basically pointers to their respective locations.

Comment: In the case that it has zero, one, or two children, elif will prevent the other variables from being defined. But, then the function will still try to return values for all three -- thusly, error.

Comment: Set zero, one, two to 0,0,0 before the top if statement, remove bottom else statement.

Comment: You can do this using the yield keyword fairly simple.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the method `_node_counts_aux()` returns a tuple, but you are trying to add `1` to its result. You'll have to the pull the counts for elements of type 0, 1, and 2 out of the recursive calls and use those values instead.

Comment: For clarification, you can do that using the subscript operator -- `zero = 1 + self._node_counts_aux(node._left)[0] + self._node_counts_aux(node._right)[0]` etc. (or tuple unpacking -- below)

Comment: You can, though it's clearer to do it using assignment: `zero_left, one_left, two_left = self._node_counts_aux(node._left)`, and so on...

Comment: Yeah, I was going to write an answer suggesting tuple unpacking, but your's is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have to accumulate the results you have from the recursive calls. This can be done with `zero, one, two = map(sum, zip(result_right, result_left))`, and then adding the corresponding value depending on the number of children.

Note that I use `if/elif` statements, otherwise your code when the node has two children also enters in the next `if` block for one child.

```
def _node_counts_aux(self, node):
    zero, one, two = 0, 0, 0
    if node is not None:
        result_right = self._node_counts_aux(node._right)
        result_left = self._node_counts_aux(node._left)
        zero, one, two = map(sum, zip(result_right, result_left))
        if not node._right and not node._left:
            zero += 1
        elif node._left and node._right:
            two += 1
        elif node._left or node._right:
            one += 1
    return zero, one, two
```